# How to annotate variably in dict comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Given the following dictionary comprehension

```
{key: func(key) for key in range(5) if func(key) is not None}
```

Can I somehow annotate this `func(key)` so I won't have ‏to calculate it twice? thanks in advance

Comment: @DeepSpace Fair enough, can you add the python tag?

Comment: @coldspeed done